# KiCad: ratsnet not connecting pads

Tags: kicad

In my schematic I have a relay connected to a pin header (the two are in different `.sch` files), the connection is called `RELAY_COM`, this connection is not shown in the ratsnets in pcbnew, which prevents me from routing the two together.

I did the footprints and symbols myself for both of them, and although I rebuilt the netlist many times I cannot make the connection show up in pcbnew.

This is also true for other connections, like `RELAY_NO`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

[image: pcbnew view]

[image: schematic view]

[image]

Comment: is this using Hierarchical sheets?  if the label nets RELAY_COM associated with J1 and U5 are at the same Hierarchical level, then this should connect, ASSUMING you used "Update PCB from schematic" to ensure the netlist is imported

Comment: Another useful discussion about this topic is [here](https://forum.kicad.info/t/off-schematic-connections-and-ratsnest/9762/15)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using simple net labels. These only connect nets within one sheet.

If you are using multiple sheets, you need to use either:

- global labels: these connect everywhere
- hierarchical labels: these define connection points between sheets, essentially allowing you to treat each sheet as a component with its own pins.

See the *eeschema* documentation topics "[Wires, Buses, Labels, Power ports](https://docs.kicad.org/master/en/eeschema/eeschema.html#wires-buses-labels-power-ports)" and "[Connections - hierarchical labels](https://docs.kicad.org/master/en/eeschema/eeschema.html#connections---hierarchical-labels)" for more details.